What should I use to escape a module parameter in Joomla 5?
I have a custom module I have created.
When writing the code Chat GPT suggested that I use this code.
use Joomla\CMS\Utilities\Utility;
~
echo "<p><strong>" . Utility::escape($review['author_name']) . "</strong></p>";

However, that didn't work.  There's a stack error with utility.
It then suggested that I use:
use Joomla\CMS\HTML\HTMLHelper;
~
 echo "<p><strong>" . HTMLHelper::_('text', $review['author_name']) . "</strong></p>";

Which again didn't work.  It says that text does not exist.
It then suggested I use:
            echo "<p><strong>" . htmlspecialchars($review['author_name']) . "</strong></p>";
Which I felt was the old way of doing things, utility seemed like the new way.
Is there a preferred way to do this.  Someone said HTML Entities although looking at it htmlspecialchars should be ok in most instances I think.
I really wanted to know if there's a difference, why my code didn't work, and what is best practice.  Or what the differences are.

The proposed methods don't work simply because they don't exist. htmlspecialchars() is fine. There is no generic utility method because it would really just be a proxy to htmlspecialchars(). For completeness, HTML views and JLayouts do have an escape() method (Joomla\CMS\MVC\View\HtmlView::escape() and Joomla\CMS\Layout\BaseLayout::escape(), respectively). But again they're just proxies to htmlspecialchars().
